# Are there any sites that show how to recreate specific iOS UI paradigms?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[iDevRecipes](http://www.idevrecipes.com) is an awesome site that goes into some detail on how some popular and specific iPhone components have been developed. I was wondering if the SO crew knew of any other sites similar to this? It would be a great help to all iOS developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled across [Custom Controls for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls) last night and it looks like there are links to the source code for at least a few of the custom controls on iDev Recipes, and there are some plenty more custom controls not featured on the recipes site.  I guess it's not necessarily as pedagogical as the recipes website, but you can still browse the source code which is definitely a great way to learn about making your own custom controls.